# Pass variables via `this.props.navigation` multiple times

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

So, for begging, in `react-native-navigation` there's a possibility to pass some data via `this.props.navigation.navigate()`.

Here's how you should pass the data :

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('RouteName', {/*Data to pass*/})
```

And so, moving to the problem

### The case where this problem was encountered :

I have a list of items which I click on and I navigate to the next screen, the data of the pressed item being sent during the navigation process, and when I get to the next screen, the passed data is assigned to state, and I further operate with it. Here are the commands which I use for passing data:

#### Pass data

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2',{param1: value1, param2: value2})
```

#### Receive data

```
ComponentWillMount = () => {
    const param1 = this.props.navigation.getParam('param1');
    const param2 = this.props.navigation.getParam('param2');
    this.setState({param1, param2)}
}
```

### The Problem itself

My Problem is that if I go back to the first screen, and press on another item, then it's data isn't passed via `this.props.navigation.navigate()`, the data on the second screen remains unmodified from the first navigation process. How this problem can be resolved?

Comment: Add your code via git link or snackio which can be debugged or better if it can be added to the question itself.

Comment: At a guess, it sounds like your second screen isnt being unmounted. When you click again, react isnt creating a new screen, its navigating to the one before so componentWillMount isn't called again. Can you put a print statement in componentwillmount and see if it is really mounting? 
Are you using https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/ or https://reactnavigation.org?

Comment: @BenjaminScherer I'm using reactnavigation.org

Comment: I've added the code on the codepen

Comment: Unforetunately I can;'t run the code. It's missing to many dependencies. I tried to run it on https://snack.expo.io. 
Have you tried putting a print statement in the ComponentWillMount method? Is it printing every time you load?

Comment: If by printing you mean console.log, then yes I've tried, It shows the data only I navigate for the first time on the screen, when I go back to the previous screen and try to repeat the steps, then there isn't shown any data...

Comment: I would try moving the param extraction into the render method. you dont actually need to set or use state at all then

Comment: Tried it, isn't working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184772/discussion-between-benjamin-scherer-and-eugen-andrei-coliban).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i figured it out,
I was able to replicate the issue using drawerNavigator and tabbed navigator in the react-navigation 3.0.5.
Basically they save the components even when you run navigation.goBack.
The screen isn't being mounted again so it doesnt call componentWillMount()  and it doesn't check for data there.

there are 2 (edit 3) ways to fix this.

one is to turn off this performance enhancement

```
const MyApp = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Screen1: Screen1,
    Screen2: Screen2
  },
  {
    unmountInactiveRoutes: true
  }
);
```

The **second option** and the more elegant one is to **subscribe to navigation events**

```
componentWillMount() {
    console.log("mounting");
    const willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
        "willFocus",
        () => {
            console.debug("willFocus");
            const thing = this.props.navigation.getParam("thing");
            const thing2 = this.props.navigation.getParam("thing2");
            this.setState({thing, thing2});
        }
    );
}
```

Just dont forget to unsubscribe in componentWillUnmount

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    willFocusSubscription.remove();
}
```

The **third way** is basically the same as the second but **subscribing declaratively**. This means no componentWillMount or WillUnmount.

First a callback to set the state appropriately

```
willFocus = ({action}) => {
    console.debug("willFocus", action);
    const thing = action.params["thing"];
    const thing2 = action.params["thing2"];
    this.setState({thing, thing2});
};
```

now in render add the component

```
render() {
    console.log("data is:", this.state.thing);
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <NavigationEvents
                onWillFocus={this.willFocus} 
            />
          .... rest of render body
        </View>
    );
}
```

This doesn't display anything but it takes care of subscribing and unsubscribing.

Comment: Neither of this solutions didn't help in my case. I'm using a bottomTabNavigator...

Comment: I jus checked out tab navigator. TabbedNavigator also keeps screens in the background instead of unmounting the component. 
If i pull the passed params in componentWillMount then it only happens once. 
If i subscribe to the willFocus and perform the check there it works.

Comment: I've tried the thing with `NavigationEvents` now, and it solved my problem, thanks :)